# Pass constructor argument mock

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class `Channel` that receive in the constructor the port where need to make the call

I want to mock partially the class, and for some method use the real implementation.

I know I can use `thenCallRealMethod` but in order to use this `connect` method, my mock need to have the port, which as I mention I'm passing in the constructor.

```
Channel  chan= mock(Channel.class);
when(chan.handle()).thenReturn("Ok");    // Mock implementation
when(chan.connect()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Any idea how to make it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `spy` instead of `mock`:

```java
Channel channel = new Channel(portNumber);
Channel spyChannel = Mockito.spy(channel);
when(spyChannel.handle()).thenReturn("Ok");    // Mock implementation
//when(chan.connect()).thenCallRealMethod();  now it calls real method by default
spyChannel.connect();
```

please take a look at this tutorial as well, probably it will solve your issue:
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy

Comment: Answer with just a tutorial link provided is considered poor. Please add some code sample